# How to draw the below patterns on the path which is drawn using the Point

Tags: design-patterns, line, draw, using, paperjs

It was easy if we used the rectangle to connect.Since we used the points to draw path and set the strokeWidth to look like rectangle.
Can someone please help us to draw the below 3 patterns on path (which is just 2 points connected with strokeWidth)

[image]

Comment: Do you want a rectangle with that pattern as the Path *background*? Or do you want that pattern as the Path *stroke*?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way of doing this with Paper.js but you can make use of a rectangle as clipping mask to workaround it.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating a simplified solution which you should be able to adapt to your specific use case.

```js
const rectangle = new Path.Rectangle({
    from: view.center - [300, 50],
    to: view.center + [300, 50],
    fillColor: 'orange'
});

const spaceBetweenLines = 10;
const height = rectangle.bounds.height;
const totalWidth = rectangle.bounds.width + height;
const steps = Math.ceil(totalWidth / spaceBetweenLines);

const linesGroup = new Group();
for (let i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    const x = i * spaceBetweenLines;
    const line = new Path.Line({
        from: [x, 0],
        to: [x + height, height],
        strokeColor: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 2
    });
    linesGroup.addChild(line);
}
linesGroup.position = rectangle.position;

const clipGroup = new Group({
    children: [rectangle.clone(), rectangle, linesGroup],
    clipped: true
});
```